# Pass data via GET to a form with square brackets

Tags: string, forms, field

We've been trying to pass data to a form on a WordPress site that uses a plugin called WPForms. The name of the fields is what makes it hard to figure out how to select the field and pass it on the string. One of the fields is:

`<input type="text" id="wpforms-13800-field_3" class="wpforms-field-large wpforms-field-required" name="wpforms[fields][3]" >`

So trying to pass data in a normal GET request using the following strings won't work:

`http://example.com/form/?wpforms[fields][3]=a`

`http://example.com/form/?fields=c,b,a`

Is there anything else I should try? I would like to add that we don't have control over that form, it is hosted on a provider's website and they handle everything, we just need to pass some initial data to their form so that our customers don't have to type everything.

I'll appreciate any suggestions. Thanx.

Comment: Since you can't modify the form, can you implement javascript? That will probably best work as you can have more control. On the page that has the embedded form you simply loop through the query string and change the value of the appropriate form fields based on field name.

Comment: @imvain2, the page is on an external site and we cannot open the new page using iFrames as per agreement. Nice suggestion though.